# ORM for firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Are there any ORMs that support firestore in nodejs? I especially used to like ndb in python.

Comment: I'm not aware of any so far (and we haven't created any).

Answer (score 13):

We're working on one (by we I mean [Invertase / creators of react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase)). If you've used mongoose or waterline on node before then you'll find it overly familiar as that's what we're using for inspiration.

This is all still internal, but to give you an idea of the api here's one of the models / usages examples we have internally:

```js
const User = model('User', {
  // auto create/update date fields
  autoCreatedAt: true,
  autoUpdatedAt: true,

  // auto created/updated by fields, uses current auth user or 'service-account'
  autoUpdatedBy: true,
  autoCreatedBy: true,

  // toggle schema/less. If turned off, this will allow you to store arbitrary
  // data in a record. If turned on, only attributes defined in the model's
  // attributes object will be stored.
  schema: true,

  attributes: {
    first_name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    last_name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    // virtual field support
    full_name() {
      return `${this.first_name} ${this.last_name}`;
    },

    age: {
      type: 'integer'
    },
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      required: true
    },
    someBool: {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false
    },

    // association example- in this case a child collection of the users doc
    // e.g /users/id/posts
    posts: {
      collection: 'posts',
    }
  }
});

// magic methods based on attributes
// findByX or findOneByX
User.findByAge(27).then((val) => {
  // val = [] or [document object]
}).catch((error) => {
  debugger;
});

// magic methods based on attributes
// findByX or findOneByX
User.findByName('mike').then((val) => {
  // val = [] or [document object]
}).catch((error) => {
  debugger;
});

// find a single document
User.findOne().then((val) => {
  // val = undefined or document object
}).catch((error) => {
  debugger;
});

// find multiple docs
User.find({
  name: 'mike',
  age: 27,
  someBool: true,
}).then((val) => {
  // val = [] or [document object]
}).catch((error) => {
  debugger;
});

// find multiple docs with age between range
User.find({
  someBool: true,
  age: {
    $gte: 27,
    $lte: 35
  }
}).then((val) => {
  // val = [] or [document object]
}).catch((error) => {
  debugger;
});
```

Keep an eye out on our discord, Github org or twitter - hope to have a public alpha in a few days.

The example above doesn't showcase everything we're planning but we're planning to support things like paginations (skip, limit, page), createOrUpdate, findOrCreate, subscribe() - for realtime, multiple range filters (first one sent to firestore, the rest done client side) etc

**Update:**

A very early on repo has been made public on github [here](https://github.com/invertase/firepit). It generally works, docs still need doing and a few things missing code wise - for usage see the tests - it's well tested (test driven development), if you'd like to contribute then please do :) we're on pause for Firepit right now as we're pushing a release of React Native Firebase at the moment.

Comment: how this coming along?

Comment: @sirvon description updated with more information + repo link

Comment: What happened to this project?

Comment: That looked so promising, but seems that the repo is off github. Have you retired it, or it's in private development?

Comment: @GlebKost it's very much still in active development, dm me on twitter and I can give you access/more info on the internal copy of it that's being worked on. (have just dropped you a follow on twitter)

Comment: @Salakar How can I get my hands on it?

Comment: It seems to be private :(

Comment: Hi, @Salakar this is still in development? I interested in this solution. This solution is open source? Can I get an early access version?